# Is it a good idea to have a central static ClientContext for communication from silverlight client to sharepoint ?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to render the UI by retrieving the listitems from sharepoint? so what is the best way to do it asyncronously?